# Wordpress: how to show next post title

Tags: wordpress

```
  <?php next_post_link( '%link', '<strong>Next</strong>', TRUE  ); ?>
```

How to show next post title instead "Next"? I still need to keep within the same category.

Comment: Replace `Next` with `%title`. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link#Parameters

Answer (score 2):

As Sally mentioned, you could use `%title` or you could use: `get_next_post()->post_title`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code instead of what you are using :

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); ?>
```

This works for me,hope will work for you too.